# How to find singular solutions and determine their types for system of equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

> Given equations $x^\prime=x(1-x-2y)$ and $y^\prime=y(1-y-4x)$ find all the singular solutions in the upper quadrant, $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$ and determine the type and stability.

So for singular solutions I believe I want points such that:

$x(1-x-2y)=y(1-y-4x)=0$

Which gives me $x=0,y=0$ or $(1-x-2y)=(1-y-4x)\implies y=3x$

So I have solutions $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1/7,3/7)$

So I have the Jacobin matrix, $J=\begin{pmatrix} 1-2x-2y & -2x\\-4y&1-2y-4x\\ \end{pmatrix}$

And I need to evaluate the eigenvalues at different critical points.

$J(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Which is already diagonal and has $1$ repeated real positive eigenvalue.

$J(0,1)$ has $1$ repeated negative eigenvalue

$J(1,0)$ has eigenvalues $-3,0$

$J(1/7,3/7)$ has one positive and one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: do you know any of the initial conditions?

Comment: @HenryLee Doesn't have initial conditions.

Comment: There are no singularities in this equation. The system is explicit with polynomial right side, which is everywhere regular. But you can compute critical, stationary or equilibrium points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to simultaneously solve

$$x(1-x-2y) = 0 \\y (1-y-4x)=0$$

Clearly, $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

When $x = 0$, we have $y(1 - y) = 0 \implies y = 0, y = 1$.

When $y = 0$, we have $x(1 - x) = 0 \implies x = 0, x = 1$.

Then we have

$$(1-x-2y) = 0 \\ (1-y-4x)=0$$

This gives us $x = \dfrac{1}{7}, y = \dfrac{3}{7}$.

So, our critical points are

$$(x, y) = (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), \left(\dfrac{1}{7}, \dfrac{3}{7}\right)$$

Here is a contour plot that verifies this

[image]

Can you continue?

**Hints:**

Here is a phase portrait as a guide

[image]

Find the Jacobin matrix and evaluate the eigenvalues at each critical point while keeping track of any degenerate cases.

**Update:** For the Jacobian, I get

$$J(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} -2 x-2 y+1 & -2 x \\ -4 y & -4 x-2 y+1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

My [*answer*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434127/determine-all-the-critical-points-of-the-given-system-and-discuss-their-type-and) might also be helpful.

Comment: So I get that $J(0,0)$ is an unstable node, $J(0,1)$ is a stable node, $J(1/7,3/7)$ is an unstable saddle point. Im not sure about $J(1,0)$ I got that it has a zero eigenvalue and $1$ negative eigenvalue. I edited my post with the Jacobin I computed.

Comment: My Jacobian does not match yours.